# Folding on sequence of blocks

Tags: scala, functional-programming, fold, method-chaining

I want to implement chain-of-actions in my Scala code. I thought I can use "fold" for this. So, let's say I have my sequence of actions declared like this:

```
val chainOfActions: Seq[String => String] = Seq(
  {resultFromPreviousAction => 
    println("Inside the first action")
    "Result from the first action"
  },
  {resultFromPreviousAction => 
    println("Inside the second action")
    resultFromPreviousAction + " > " + "Result from the second action"
  }
)
```

The above code compiles (I tried inside scala console).

The next would be to apply the fold:

```
chainOfActions.fold("") { (intermediateText, action) =>
  action(intermediateText)
}
```

But the above code is giving the following error:

```
<console>:10: error: Object does not take parameters
                action(intermediateText)
```

Hmm... why I is action losing its type (I was expecting the type to be "String => String") ?

So I tried declaring the type:

```
type MyBlockType = String => String
```

And declare my Seq this way:

```
val chainOfActions: Seq[MyBlockType] = Seq(
  {resultFromPreviousAction => 
    println("Inside the first action")
    "Result from the first action"
  },
  {resultFromPreviousAction => 
    println("Inside the second action")
    resultFromPreviousAction + " > " + "Result from the second action"
  }
)
```

Still, getting the same error. So, I tried to check the actual type of "action"...:

```
chainOfActions.fold("") { (intermediateText, action) =>
  println(action.getClass)
  "Test it"
}
```

I'm getting this info in the console:

```
class $line101.$read$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$1
class $line101.$read$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$2
res58: Object = Test it
```

So..., it is correct (it's a func). But why does Scala doesn't recognize it as object?

Please help me point out where I did wrong.

Thanks,
Raka

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case you need 'foldLeft':

```
val result = chainOfActions.foldLeft("") {
  case (intermediateText, action) => action(intermediateText)
}
```

With fold you need to have the same type for initial value and for each value in your Seq. But your initial (and output) value is String, but collections is of String => String

Method signatures:

```
 def fold[A1 >: A](z: A1)(op: (A1, A1) => A1): A1
 def foldLeft[B](z: B)(op: (B, A) => B): B
```

So if you want to use fold your initial values need to be String => String, for example with identity it will be:

```
val result = chainOfActions.fold(identity[String] _)((l, r) => l andThen r).apply("")
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! That difference in type you mentioned caused scala to downcast to Object.

Otherwise (if my initial value is String => String), I guess I would be able to forgo the pattern matching, right?

Comment: @user3443096 yes, should work without pattern matching. try this `val result = chainOfActions.foldLeft("")(_ _)`

Comment: @Eugene : it works (that one with identity). Let me grasp the magic :)... at_Sergey: the line you gave me didn't work. It gives: <console>:9: error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => chainOfActions.foldLeft("")((x$1: (() => <empty>))))
       val result = chainOfActions.foldLeft("")(_ _)

Comment: By the way.... I just learned that can be achieved in one line of code :D : Function.chain(chainOfActions)("")